# Error: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily reenable it,you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration

Tags: facebook, ios5, xcode4.3

I am doing facebook integration part in my project. I downloaded facebook integration sample project from *rey wenderlich* and then changed `appkey` and `appsecretkey`. When I run this app, login validation is working fine and then it shows error.

> ERROR: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily reenable it, you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be disabled permanently on August 1, 2012.

Is there a workaround or are you aware of the problem and working on a fix.

Comment: ya same problem ...did u get the solution??

Comment: How you resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: the example you've copied is using some Facebook api that has been deprecated & disabled since August 2012.  You therefore need to update your code accordingly.

[This section of the Completed Changes page](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/#august-2012) lists deprecations that became effective on the date mentioned.  I would guess you're either using `prompt_permissions.php` or `prompt_feed.php`;  upgrade as described in the page.